# OpenSAML custom attribute value

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I'm trying to create a SAML response. One of the attributes that makes up the assertion is called address and the attribute value needs to be a custom type that is defined in an XSD. How do I add custom attribute value types to the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your attribute value XML is in String form:

```
String yourXMLFragment = "...";

AttributeStatementBuilder attributeStatementBuilder = 
   (AttributeStatementBuilder) builderFactory.getBuilder(AttributeStatement.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
AttributeStatement attributeStatement = attributeStatementBuilder.buildObject();

AttributeBuilder attributeBuilder = 
   (AttributeBuilder) builderFactory.getBuilder(Attribute.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
Attribute attr = attributeBuilder.buildObject();
attr.setName("yourAttributeName");

XSAnyBuilder sb2 = (XSAnyBuilder) builderFactory.getBuilder(XSAny.TYPE_NAME);
XSAny attrAny = sb2.buildObject(AttributeValue.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME, XSAny.TYPE_NAME);
attrAny.setTextContent(yourXMLFragment.trim());

attr.getAttributeValues().add(attrAny);
attributeStatement.getAttributes().add(attr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this above does not yeld correct results. The above example can be used only to create xsany with text content not xml content (xml content gets escaped).

So after digging in opensaml sources the following did work as needed:

```
public XSAny createXSAny(Element dom)
{
XSAnyBuilder anyBuilder = (XSAnyBuilder) Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(XSAny.TYPE_NAME);
    XSAny any = anyBuilder.buildObject(AttributeValue.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME, XSAny.TYPE_NAME);
    // this builds only the root element not the whole dom
    XSAny xo=anyBuilder.buildObject(dom);
    // set/populate dom so whole dom gets into picture
    xo.setDOM(dom);
    any.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(xo);

  return any; 
}
```